# PHP file_get_contents with zip://: failed to open stream: operation failed

Tags: php, file, permissions, zip

I'm trying to read a file from a ZIP archive with the `zip://` steam operator. This file has been downloaded from the internet. My code is as follows:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/file.zip';
file_put_contents(getcwd().'/temp.zip', fopen($url, 'r'));
chmod(getcwd() . '/temp.zip', 777);

$fileName = 'FILE_IN_ZIP.xml';
$data = file_get_contents('zip://' .  realpath('temp.zip') . '#' . $fileName);
```

The error is as follows:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(zip://path/to/temp.zip#FILE_IN_ZIP.xml): failed to open stream: operation failed in /my/project/directory/test.php on line 10
```

I'm sure it's not a permissions issue since I give 777 permissions on the file, the directory this all happens in has 777 permissions (recursively) and the error doesn't say so. If `file_get_contents()` can't read it because of bad permissions, it'll say `failed to open stream: Permission denied`.

I'm also sure the file exists. I can obviously see it when I unzip the file manually and if it doesn't, `file_get_contents()` should say `failed to open stream: No such file or directory`.

The archive also isn't corrupt, I can unzip it manually just fine. This all runs on a Mac (macOS 10.12 Sierra).

PHP Version information:

```
$: php --version
PHP 7.0.3 (cli) (built: Feb  6 2016 03:16:24) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Seems like the path `zip://path/to/temp.zip#FILE_IN_ZIP.xml` is wrong. Check it. Also you can try with `realpath`

Comment: @S.I. Mate, as you can see, I do use `realpath()` already. The file definitely exists.

Comment: Yeah, my fault but for me `file_get_contents` can't find it or can't open it.

Comment: Is `zip` in the list returned by `stream_get_wrappers()` ?

Comment: @apokryfos 

>>> stream_get_wrappers()
=> [
     "https",
     "ftps",
     "compress.zlib",
     "compress.bzip2",
     "php",
     "file",
     "glob",
     "data",
     "http",
     "ftp",
     "phar",
     "zip",
   ]

yup

Comment: I was in the same situation because spaces in the filename